# plotting with black background in octave: keeping background color in print file

Tags: plot, octave

I am using octave (4.2.2) to make a figure with a black background.

```
clear;clf
%% circle
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,91);xc=cos(theta);yc=sin(theta);
fill(0.3*xc,0.3*yc,[0,0.5,0.5]);hold on
set(gca,'color',[0 0 0])
```

This script accomplishes that on the terminal, however if I print the figure using

```
print -dpng black.back.png
```

the image has a white background.  If the set color command is changed to [1,1,1], both the figure displayed on the terminal and the printed image have a white background.  Can anyone suggest a way to save an image with a black background to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a remnant from the early days (way before Windows came around) when the display background was black by default, but paper was white as it has always been. Figures have a property called `InvertHardCopy` that is (still, after all these years) on by default. This property causes figures and axes to be printed with a white background.

Set it off for your expected behavior:

```
set(gcf,'InvertHardCopy','off')
```

[See the MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-InvertHardcopy). [The Octave docs have a similar entry](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Figure-Properties.html).

Comment: I like when a good teacher solves my problem and gives me a history lesson to help me remember, thank you!